# Samsung Gio overheating and no power

Tags: samsung-galaxy-gio, overheating

I have a Gio and recently have an issue with the phone being hot and not responding.  I have to pull the battery to get the phone to work.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try replacing battery. Restore phone via factory reset

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a hot area (in a car, outside in Florida) this may happen simply because of the surrounding temperature. If this is happening regularly under normal conditions, you may want to contact your seller, as the problem is most likely with the hardware of the phone or battery.